# I don't see all the asked questions

Tags: support, stack-overflow, asking-questions, javascript

In Stack Overflow, when visit any user account page, including my own, I can't see all the asked questions. On the pager, I see the "next" link, but it doesn't work for all users, and I can only see the last asked question

what is the cause of this issue? Is it a JavaScript issue, or something else?

Comment: Which browser? It's working on my Chrome though.

Comment: i am using mozila fierfox

Comment: @Mihir, which version of Firefox? Have you done hard refreshing the page with Ctrl+F5?

Comment: i am using version 3.0.8.. Mozilla Firefox for in Ubuntu canonial-1.0

Comment: hey i have tied same with google chrome and its working there..

Comment: in that page, press CTRL + F5 to do a hard refresh. See if that works

Comment: pressing ctrl+f5 not working in my fierfox

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about issue with Firefox 3.0.8 which is not supported by SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you update your browser to 3.6 and above?

According to this one, 3.0.8 is not under supported list

[Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported/71208#71208)

Comment: Right. I wonder if this is an Ajax issue, but as it's an old browser that might just be one of many possible causes.

Comment: i have downloaded firefox 4 on my ubantu and it is working. Thanks for your help